# Using @modifying with spring r2dbc

Tags: spring, spring-data, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

As I understand you should use `@Modifying` whenever you write for example update query with `@Query` annotation, but I've seen many times people don't use that annotation when using `R2dbcRepository` or `CoroutineCrudRepository`, so should I use this annotation using reactive stack or no?

Is there a case that I don't have to use `@Modifying` if I don't really use entity manager and don't use `@Entity`?

Comment: It is only when data is changed, you don't need it when you are selecting data with an `@Query` annotated method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I get that, I was wondering about update queries

Comment: Is there a case that I don't have to use @Modifying if I don't really use entity manager and don't use @Entity?

Comment: The `@Modifying` is part of Spring Data JPA so I doubt it it useful on anything else.

Comment: I use `R2dbcRepository` which is part of `springframework.data.r2dbc`, shouldn't I use `@Modifying` in that case?

Comment: As stated is is part of Spring Data **JPA** not Spring Data **R2DBC**. So the annotation isn't even available to you (unless you are also using JPA in your application).

Comment: there is also `@Modyfing` in `springframework.data.r2dbc`

Comment: Well then use it (and [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/repository/Modifying.html) explains when to use it and when not).

Comment: what's the point of using it if the queries works perfectly fine without it?

Comment: Because you are probably either without a proper tx context (and thus have auto commit behavior) or have enabled some sort of auto committing.

Answer (score 0):

It's there:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/r2dbc/query-methods.html#r2dbc.repositories.modifying

```java
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE person SET firstname = :firstname where lastname = :lastname")
Mono<Integer> setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);
```